# echo html only if the variable is not empty

Tags: php

I am trying to print the content of the variable and a `<hr>` tag after doing a check if the variable is not empty. The `<hr>` is getting echoed even if the variable is empty.

Here is what I have

```
<?php if (!empty($content['relationship_graph'])){ 
            print render($content['relationship_graph']);
            echo '<hr>';
          }
         ?>
```

Not very pro in PHP but looked at some documentation...Cant seem to figure out what I might be doing wrong

Comment: What does `render()` do? Can you echo out `$content['relationship_graph']` inside your if statement?

Comment: try var_dump($content['relationship-graph']);

Comment: @Fred that's totally wrong.
It will only echo if the variable is empty. You don't need an else statement if the only other option is to do nothing.

Comment: @Jhawins I might've not completely understood the question. However, can the OP not add a condition to not print the HR if otherwise?

Comment: You don't need an else statement for **not** printing the statement.

Comment: Are you sure that `$content['relationship_graph']` is really empty?

Comment: @fa7d0 That's what I am also thinking (now) byte order mark maybe, or a space? Maybe something that wrote an `\n` and is counting as a character.

Comment: $content['relationship_graph'] was not really empty. So I had to do this 
if ($content['relationship_graph']['#markup']['length'] != 0

Even though relationship_graph is an array it wasn't really empty.

Comment: @Jhawins Here, as per: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154754/echo-html-only-if-the-variable-is-not-empty?noredirect=1#comment26592782_18154754

Answer (score 1):

Value in it could be a blank space.

try..

```
<?php 
    if(!empty($content['relationship_graph']) && $content['relationship_graph']!=''){ 
        print render($content['relationship_graph']);
        echo '<hr>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: @Rahul-- Thanks for posting the solution. Apparently it didnt really work. I got it working any way. Thanks :-)

Comment: @soum: if your issue was resolved, consider posting it as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing. It worked.

```
if($content['relationship_graph']['#markup']['length'] != 0){
                  print render($content['relationship_graph']);
                  echo '<hr>';
              }
```

Comment: Note that `$content['relationship_graph']` is NOT empty because it is an array with at least one element name `'#markup'`. Only arrays with no elements inside are considered empty.